# Python finding nth occurrence of forward slash

Tags: python

I have some URLs in a JSON file, and I'm trying to extract just the image name (i.e. 1234_5678.jpg). The URLs look like this:

> "display_url":
> "https://scontent-ort2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/42672335_535716956833725_410505336278760344_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-ort2-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=109&_nc_ohc=PCKXombie-oAX-T37mi&tp=1&oh=69744106833b4fa24cb921e6e1009d32&oe=6024044B&ig_cache_key=MTg5ODMzNjQ1NzMwMTM4Njg2Nw%3D%3D.2"

I decided the method to use would be to locate the 6th occurrence of the forward slash, as well as the `.jpg`, and extract the substring between them:

```
import json


def findnth(haystack, needle, n):
    parts= haystack.split(needle, n+1)
    if len(parts)<=n+1:
        return -1
    return len(haystack)-len(parts[-1])-len(needle)

with open('pathtofile.json', encoding='utf8') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for p in data['GraphImages']:
        url = p['display_url']
        start = findnth(url, "/", 6)
        end = url.find(".jpg")
        print(start)
        print(end)

        url = url[start:end+3]
```

However, the start value is always -1. The end value is between 90-110, which seems reasonable. Why isn't my nth search function locating the appropriate location?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `urlparse`

**Ex:**

```
import os
from urllib.parse import urlparse
url = "https://scontent-ort2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/42672335_535716956833725_410505336278760344_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-ort2-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=109&_nc_ohc=PCKXombie-oAX-T37mi&tp=1&oh=69744106833b4fa24cb921e6e1009d32&oe=6024044B&ig_cache_key=MTg5ODMzNjQ1NzMwMTM4Njg2Nw%3D%3D.2"
o = urlparse(url)

print(os.path.basename(o.path))
# --> 42672335_535716956833725_410505336278760344_n.jpg
```